# Path to file in the Assets folder from within a Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using a plugin [cordova-plugin-bluenet-dfu](https://github.com/dobots/cordova-plugin-bluenet-dfu) I put the required firmware directly within the www folder. However, I have trouble targeting the file correctly with either file path or URI.

With `filePath` for example, the plugin in Java opens file the following way:

```
final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

I tried to specify the file by

```
file:///android_asset/www/firmware/sdk11_lock_20161215_resDelay.zip
android_asset/www/firmware/sdk11_lock_20161215_resDelay.zip
www/firmware/sdk11_lock_20161215_resDelay.zip
```

None of which seems to work. I tried the first one with `fileUri` too and it doesn't work.

How do I specify the path to the file inside the the `assets` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova access your file as a relative path. Mainly, Cordova think you're using the www directory. So if you want to find a file, i.e. myfile.html, you just use this filename if the file is in the www dir. 
If the file is in the dir inside (i.e. www\MyDirInside), you can access to it using MyDirInside\myfile.html (Sincerely I don't remember if \ or / ).

Let's try using your dir and files.

Comment: That's weird. I'm pretty sure it's forward slash ("/") as it is not Windows. But I can't seem to access it though. :( `www/firmware/sdk11_lock_20161215_resDelay.zip` doesn't work even though that's where I placed it.

Comment: Did you also tried firmware/sdk11_lock_20161215_resDelay.zip ?

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't work. I created a simple  Android cordova plugin and I still cannot access something as simple as www/index.html

Comment: After much fiddling I realized you're right. I wasn't able to realize sooner that compressed files doesn't work in asset. :)